# see virtual/recent buffers when switching with fido

Tags: completing-read, builtin, icomplete, fido

I've switched from ido to fido and I'm missing the feature of being able to open recently closed buffers that `ido-mode` provided with `ido-use-virtual-buffers`. I spent a lot of time searching for how to get this and reading all about icomplete and do know that I can add the consult package to obtain this function but I'm not going to do that until I'm more familiar with emacs built-ins.

Is there a way to get recentf entries to be appended after the open buffers when I call `switch-to-buffer` using `fido-vertical-mode`?

If not, is there a way to use `ido-mode` just for buffer switching without it conflicting with icomplete?